# How to pass a value from a jquery plugin to its callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple Jquery function that takes a few parameters and comes up with some kind of result. I need to be able to pass this result to the call Back function of the jquery plugin.

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.newPlugin= function(params,CBfunction){

    //do some stuff;
    var result = "something";
    CBfunction.call(this);

}; 
})( jQuery );
```

when I use the plugin I want to be able to parse the result of the plugin to the callback function:

```
$(elm).newPlugin(params, function(params, this.result){
  //this.resullt comes from the plugin ('something');

})
```

Is this possible?

For example look at the variable "myVar":

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.newPlugin= function(a,b,CBfunction){

    myVar = a+b;

    CBfunction.call(this);

}; 
})( jQuery );
```

I use the plugin:

```
$(elm).newPlugin(a,b,function(){
  alert("the result of "+a+" + "+b+" is:"+myVar);
})
```

myVar comes from the plugin and used in the callback function, is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "parse the result of the plugin to the callback"...

Comment: Is it your own plugin that you are writing?

Comment: I am guessing he actually means "pass" not "parse".

Comment: lets say that $(elm).height() returns the height of an element, I want to use this value into the callback functon, height doesn't have one, but fadeIn does, "imagine: that fadeIn() returns some value and you want to use that value n the callback function $(elm).fadeIn(100, function(value){ //do something with value });

Comment: I modified my question, maybe it is more clear now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just pass the result when you call the callback? Like this:

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.newPlugin= function(params,CBfunction){

    //do some stuff;
    var result = "something";
    CBfunction.call(this, result);
};
})(jQuery);
```

Then you need to modify your call to look like this (by the way, notice that I removed the 'param' parameter form the callback, because only one parameter is being passed):

```
$(elm).newPlugin(params, function(result){
  // result comes from the plugin ('something');
})
```

Comment: will this allow me to pass more variables and "result" ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass as many variables as you want, just like any other function call. The only difference ".call" has over a normal function call is that it allows you to specify what the "this" keyword value should be inside the callback.

Comment: this means that the person to use the plugin must use "result" as a specific variable coming from the plugin, how does the function will now who is result if I pass 2 or 3 or n variables?

Comment: I just realised you also had a mistake in your callback definition in that you have another parameter call 'param', which shouldn't be there.

Comment: To answer your question, this is something that you have to tell your users about, e.g. in the documentation. Just like any callback, the user need to know what parameters is it going to receive.

Comment: For example, if I create a handler for a mouseclick event, then I might want to pass two parameters x and y for the user to know where the mouse was clicked, or I can pass a dictionary like {x: ..., y: ...}. As you can see, there is no way for the user to tell what is being sent unless they debug/read your code, or you document this somewhere.

Comment: In fadeIn(), the callback function is independent from fadeIn(), $(elm).fadeIn(300, function(){
  alert(hello);
}); How do I take hello from FadeIn() ??? (fadeIn() doesn't generate a variable hello, but my plugin does.)

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand you here to be honest. I thought you want to pass some result from the plugin to the callback, right? As for fadeIn(), they just don't have any result to pass because the callback is called when the animation (fading) is completed, so there is not much to send.

Comment: Yes, I that is why I said fadeIn doesnt have any result to pass, but as an example, mine does. After my plugin is done doing whatever it has to do it will generate a variable "result" I want the callback to be able to use "result" how do I pass it?

Comment: Yeah, exactly like my answer! It is calling the callback and passing 'result' to it, and then the callback can do whatever it needs to do with the result you passed it. I am getting confused now :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47111/discussion-between-rafid-and-eddy-xp)

Comment: Hahahaha! I got it now it worked :), I was so confused, but just the way you said, I know exactly what you meant now, thanks a lot!